# Modifying DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in environment variables

Tags: python, django

I've come across a very dumb yet irritating problem when running my Django server. When running the server it says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apolo_client.setting'

I don't know where I've set this variable to `apollo_client.setting`. Obviously it's supposed to be "settings" with an ‘s’ at the end. I tried manually setting the variable in windows and even in python itself, but it doesn't work. I tried retrieving the variable in `__init__.py` file in django's conf folder and it says `apollo_client.setting`! However running `os.environ` anywhere else in windows gives the current output. 
Is there a way I could reset the value or maybe search for the bit where it's being set to the wrong valule?

Comment: Are you running via `manage.py`? Check the file if so, you might have modified it (It usually sets `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in its code).

Answer (score 0):

The [ModuleNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError) is an exception raised by Python when it cannot find an imported module.

From the docs:

> A subclass of ImportError which is raised by import when a module could not be located. It is also raised when None is found in sys.modules. 
> [The Python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError)

See the [Source code for django.utils.module_loading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/_modules/django/utils/module_loading/)

In your case, I believe the `apollo_client.setting` module is missing. Check if it is properly installed by running `pip freeze` to freeze and output the content of your working environment. This way you will see all modules you have installed.

*if you are working in an isolated environment —highly recommended— you must first activate your environment.*

Comment: Check if you have installed the library [apollo-client.](https://pypi.org/project/apollo-client/#data)